# Cambiar el rótulo de los ejes

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.x

Quiero cambiar el rótulo de los ejes pero no puedo, este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#busco el archivo con el cual voy a trabajar:

CWD_NORTE = pd.read_excel ("/home/florencia/Documentos/RADA2018/CWD_NORTE.xlsx")
CWD_NORTE.head

cwdNorte = list(CWD_NORTE.values.flatten())
cwdNorte

#quiero que cada fila sea un vector
s1 = cwdNorte[0:27] 
s2 = cwdNorte[27:54] 
s3 = cwdNorte[54:81] 
s4 = cwdNorte[81:108] 
s5 = cwdNorte[108:135]
s6 = cwdNorte[135:162]
s7 = cwdNorte[162:189]
s8 = cwdNorte[189:216]
s9 = cwdNorte[216:243]
s10 = cwdNorte[243:270]
s11 = cwdNorte[270:297]
s12 = cwdNorte[297:324]
s13 = cwdNorte[324:351]

print s1
print s2
print s3
print s4
print s5
print s6
print s7
print s8
print s9
print s10
print s11
print s12
print s13

sList = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13] 


#genero el boxplot:

plt.boxplot(sList)


#vamos a mejorar la imagen:

fig , ax1=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax1.set_title("CWD_NORTE") #titulo
ax1.set_xlabel('modelos') #nombre del eje x
ax1.set_ylabel('dias') #nombre del eje y
ax1.plot()
#indice = np.arange(13)
#plt.ax1_xticks(np.arange("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",) )
bp = ax1.boxplot(sList) #genero el boxplot
```

Probé usando el `np.arange` pero no funciona.

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo apreciaría mucho.

Comment: ¿Qué sale cuando corres el código así?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar la etiqueta de cada dataset puedes usar el argumento `labels` de `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sList = np.random.randint(1, 30, (10, 13)) # Datos aleatorios a modo de ejemplo

fig , ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax1.set_title("CWD_NORTE") #titulo
ax1.set_xlabel('modelos') #nombre del eje x
ax1.set_ylabel('dias') #nombre del eje y
labels = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M")
ax1.boxplot(sList, labels=labels) #genero el boxplot

# ax1.boxplot(sList)
# ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
fig.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una observación aparte, `import matplotlib as np` supongo que es un typo, es `import numpy as np`, de cualquier forma intentas usar [`numpy.arrange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) con un fin incorrecto, dicha función generar un array con valores comprendidos entre dos límites y con un paso entre ellos determinado, similar a `range` en Python:

```
>>> np.arange(1, 20, 2)
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

---

### **Edición:**

Si quieres rotar las etiquetas puedes usar [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) en su lugar 
 y el argumento `rotate` al que se le pasa el ángulo. Para modificar el rango numérico del eje `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ytick` y el anteriormente comentado `numpy.arange`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sList = np.random.randint(1, 30, (10, 13))

fig , ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax1.set_title("CWD_NORTE") #titulo
ax1.set_xlabel('modelos') #nombre del eje x
ax1.set_ylabel('dias') #nombre del eje y
labels = ("Modelo {}".format(n) for n in range(0, 13))
ax1.boxplot(sList) #genero el boxplot
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 61, 5))
fig.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que si alguna de tus cajas tiene datos que superen ese rango aparecerá un trozo de eje sin marcadores. Puedes forzar los límites del eje con `ax1.set_ylim(0, 60)`, pero esto cortará el gráfico si los datos superan el rango.

Si solo quisieras modificar el intervalo entre marcas podrías hacer:

```
start, end = ax1.get_ylim()
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(start, end, 5))
```

Comment: FJSevilla muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó mucho! Quisiera saber también como poner los rótulos en vertical, porque en vez de tener A,B,C.. tengo nombres por ejemplo: CSIRO-Mk3-6-0, ENSAMBLE... los cuales se superponen. Y por último saber como fijar el eje y que varíe entre 0 y 60, cada 5. Gracias!

Comment: @Florencia he editado la respuesta, mira a ver si es lo que buscabas. Un saludo.

Comment: logré rotar las etiquetas pero sigo teniendo problemas con el eje y. En el editor pongo:

ax1.boxplot(sList) #genero el boxplot
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 61, 5))
fig.show()

Pero me genera el eje y entre 5 y 45 (siendo el máximo valor que alcanza = 30), no entre 0 y 61 cada 5 como le pedí. Además, me advierte esto: 
** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arange' **
Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Estás importando correctamente numpy con `import numpy as np`? Como comenté en la respuesta `import matplotlib as np` es un error.

Comment: Sí, logré hacerlo con ax1.set_ylim(0, 60), pero por default lo genera con un intervalo cada 10. Me quedaron bien los gráficos. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @FJSevilla !!

Comment: Dado que usas un rango de enteros puedes usar `ax1.set_yticks(range(0, 61, 5))` pero `arange` no te debe dar error, o importas mal como en tu ejemplo (`import matplotlib as np`) o tienes algo mal en NumPy.

Comment: En otros ejemplos que usé no me generaba error con el arrange , en este sí. Pero con un intervalo cada 10 los gráficos quedaron bien.

Comment: Otra consulta, me gustaría agrandar el tamaño de la letra tanto de los ejes (no solo el nombre del eje sino los rótulos) y del título, porque se ven pequeños. Sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Hay varias formas, por ejemplo, puedes hacer `plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=15)`;
`plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=15)`;
`plt.rc('axes', titlesize=25)`;
`plt.rc('axes', labelsize=20)`, esto lo haces antes de crear la figura. Otra forma es usando el argumento `fontsize` en  los métodos `set_...`, por ejemplo `ax1.set_xlabel('modelos', fontsize=15)` , para el eje Y si no especificas las marcas manualmente puedes hacer `ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=12)`. Si tienes problemas dado que esto es prácticamente una pregunta diferente, considera crear otra pregunta en el sitio. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias! Saludos